# Angular 9 Best Practice to handle array with different objects in a Http Request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm very new to Angular and also to web development, so if I may use terms not precisely or if I explain my problem a little weird, please forgive ;-)
To the problem:
I work with Angular 9 and am making a http request (get and post) to an API via the HttpModule. The response object (as well as the post object) is a JSON object which amongst other objects includes an array with variable objects:

```
inputs: [
    {
      id: string,
      sT: string,
      stl: string,
      mCC: number
    },
    {
     id: string,      
     sT: string,
     val: string,
     dT: string
    }

  ]
```

What I read so far is, that you usually create an interface for the response object, so you can access the objects properties with the name of the property. I did this for all other properties, also for nested ones, but with the array above I have the problem, that the objects are not having the same attributes. What I did is to create an interface for 'Input' with optional attrubutes, like this:

```
// Single interface with optional attributes

export interface Input {
  id: string;
  sT: string;
  dT?: string;
  val?: string;
  mCC?: number;
  stl?: string;
}
```

But I feel, that this is not the way of how you are usually typing this sort of object.
How do you do this the 'Angularish way'? Or is this more a TS question?

I would be glad to find a best practice for this sort, as I guess I will see this type of object often in the future.

Comment: When it comes to object handling, there is no such thing as *Angularish* way. There is only JS and TS way. And from your interface, it seems about the right approach for optional properties.

Comment: Okay,thank you for your reply! I thought there may be some guideline in Angular, as e.g. it is also suggested to create interfaces instead of classes for the use in http requests (see here: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response). So I thought there may be a completely other way to work with those kinds of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not idea what kind of attributes will be return you can declare something like that

```
interface Input{
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

If you know some of the elements will be always here, you can be more precise

```
interface Input{
  id: string;
  sT: string;
  [key: string]: string|number;
}
```

If you know you have a limited random list of elements, as the six of your sample, your solution is ok.

Comment: I accept your answer for two reasons,  you seem to have experience and, furthermore, you give additional information on how to handle this object. Thank you! I did not expect such quick replies on this.